# Google function issue to load data from my firestore DB

Tags: python, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I'm studying a little the Firebase services, specially the GCF, to do that, I'm trying to get data from my Firestore NOSQL db. It should be something simple, but I'm stuck in this error:

> google.api_core.exceptions.NotFound: 404 The database (default) does not exist for project xxxx Please visit https://console.cloud.google.com/datastore/setup?project=xxxx to add a Cloud Datastore or Cloud Firestore database.

my code is simple (running in GCP)

```
import base64
import functions_framework
from google.cloud import firestore

# Triggered from a message on a Cloud Pub/Sub topic.
@functions_framework.cloud_event
def hello_pubsub(cloud_event):

    db = firestore.Client(project="xxxx")

    users_ref = db.collection("faq")
    docs = users_ref.stream()

    for doc in docs:
        print(f"{doc.id} => {doc.to_dict()}")

    # Print out the data from Pub/Sub, to prove that it worked
    print(base64.b64decode(cloud_event.data["message"]["data"]))
```

The database exists, I can see in the Firestore console and also have data (accessed by my Flutter app), but for now, I have no idea of what could be the issue here.